# Symfony Doctrine - retrieve records from a related table using the foreign key field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two related tables. One of the table has a one to many relationship to the second table. This is a sample illustration of the two tables

**

```
registration
id | firstname | membershipfk
1  | John      | 2
2  | Foo       | 3
```

**

Here is illustration of the second table

```
membership
id | type   | discount   | description     
1  | Gold   | xyz        | xyz description
2  | Silver | xyz        | xyz description
```

Now my present challenge is to retrieve the membership fields from the membership table using the foreign key in the registration table.
For example: `Select Type, Discount and Description from Membership Entity where fk in registration entity is equal to 2`

Presently in my controller I am making this attempt

```
public function getMembersAction()
        {
          $restresults = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XXXBundle:Members')->findAll();

          $data = array();
            foreach ($restresults as $restresult) {

                array_push($data, $this->serializeData($restresult));

            }
```

Every kind assistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code

```
$em->getRepository('XXXBundle:Members')
    ->createQueryBuilder('m')
    ->select("m.type, m.discount, m.description")
    ->innerJoin("XXXBundle:Registration","r","WITH","m.id = r.membershipfk") //Here you will Join with the Registration Bundle
->where("m.id = 2")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call a findBy for example if your entity are set well.

Try this:

```
$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XXXBundle:Members')->findByMember($memberId);
```

But you need to have configured well your entity first

Comment: Please what is weel

Comment: sorry for the error, It was well, you need to configure relations between entity. See doctrine documentation please @blend

Comment: so you can use method findByMember I think